# Reading integers in C until the ENTER key is pressed

Tags: c, arrays, scanf, enter

I'd like to read a variable number of integers in an array until the user hits Enter. I have managed to achieve this by doing the following:

```
printf("Give the numbers in the array, then hit ENTER: \n");
scanf("%d", &array[i]);
i++;
no_elements++;

while (scanf(line, "%d", &array[i++])== 1) {
    scanf("%d", &array[i]);
    i++;
    no_elements++;
}
```

On the other hand, I found this on a website and I don't fully understand the scanf test. It works in that the reading stops when I hit enter. However, the number of integers read ends up being equal to one regardless (checked that by adding a printf instruction). Why is that? How else could I do the same?

Note: the variable i is set as 0 in the beginning, as is no_elements; line is declared as char line[20].

Comment: There are many problems with that code, for example you reading input *twice* in the loop.

Comment: I thought I could use the first scanf just as a condition, to check whether or not the user has been adding integers only (?) What would a good option for doing that be?

Comment: To *only* use that `scanf` to both read and check. Skip the first call outside the loop, as well as the one inside the loop body.

Comment: Thank you. I'm kind of a noob, though. The number of integers no_elements is 0 after the loop now. I'm not sure it even enters the while loop.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int i=0, no_elements = 0;
    int array[16];

    while(no_elements<16){
        char line[32];
        int n;
        printf("Give the numbers in the array, then hit ENTER: \n");
        fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin);
        if(*line == '\n')
            break;
        if(1==sscanf(line, "%d", &n))
            array[no_elements++]=n;
    }
    printf("%d\n", no_elements);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{int a[100],i,sum=0,count=0;
char c;
for(i=0;c!='\n';i++)
{scanf("%d%c",&a[i],&c);
 count++;
}
for(i=0;i<count;i++)
    {sum=sum+a[i];}
printf("%d",sum);
getch();}`
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.  It's probably worth formatting the code to a more conventional layout, too.

Answer (score -1):

In C:
if the input is given as integers separated by space and after the final input if enter key is pressed we can read as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int ar[10],i=0;
    char c=' ';
    while(c!='\n'){
        scanf("%d%c",&ar[i++],&c);
    }
    while(i>0)
        printf("%d\t",ar[--i]);
 }
```

Comment: you can skip it or u can it intialize it c=""